# How to block data backup functionality for certain users?

Tags: tally

We are using Tally Prime 2.1, with a Gold multi-user license.

Backup feature in tally allows a user to take a backup of tally data to their local disk. From data security aspect, we would like to block this backup feature for certain users.

Is there any security control which we can apply user-wise for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this guide - [TallyPrime Security Configuration](https://help.tallysolutions.com/tally-prime-server/application-configuration-tallyprime-server/security-configuration-in-tallyprime-server/)

In security levels you configure whether users under that security level can backup data
[image]

Comment: Above is applicable when you are using TallyPrime Server. We don't have license for that. Is it possible without it?

Comment: If you have gold license , then we can use tally server

Comment: Sai,  thanks for the info, didn't knew that. Will try in that direction.